# tfs2010 get the user who started the buid in custom activity

Tags: continuous-integration

I need to write a custom activity for logging. Is it possible to get the user who queued build in my activity?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`IBuildDetail.RequestedFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail.requestedfor.aspx) property of the `BuildDetail` variable in your Workflow Process.